# How to reduce decimal points in UnitConverter?

Tags: swift

I write simple code to convert temperature units from kelvin to fahrenheit or celsius.

I want to remove decimal points like an 71.5999999999957 results.

Do you have any simple solution?

```
import Foundation

var base: Double = 295.14999999999998

let kelvinTemperature = Measurement.init(value: base, unit: UnitTemperature.kelvin)
let fahrenheitTemperature = kelvinTemperature.converted(to: .fahrenheit)
let celsiusTemperature = kelvinTemperature.converted(to: .celsius)

print(celsiusTemperature)
print(fahrenheitTemperature)
```

results :

22.0 °C

71.5999999999957 °F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.

```
import Foundation

var base: Double = 295.14999999999998

let kelvinTemperature = Measurement.init(value: base, unit: UnitTemperature.kelvin)
let fahrenheitTemperature = kelvinTemperature.converted(to: .fahrenheit)
let celsiusTemperature = kelvinTemperature.converted(to: .celsius)

let numFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let measureFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
measureFormatter.numberFormatter = numFormatter
let fahrenheit = measureFormatter.string(from: fahrenheitTemperature)

print(celsiusTemperature)
print(fahrenheit)
```